# Writing file: IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, ioexception, filewriter

I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting the above error with my code.  I create a new instance of both FileWriter and BufferedWriter each time the method is called, yet apparently the stream is already closed.

```
public static void addSpawn(Location spawn)
{
    File spawns = new File("spawns.dat");

    FileWriter write = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;

    try
    {
        write = new FileWriter(spawns, true);
        out = new BufferedWriter(write);

        out.write(locToStr(spawn));
        out.newLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error writing spawn file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if(write != null)
        {
            try
            {
                write.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(out != null)
        {
            try
            {
                out.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace, including an indication of which line in the code you've posted is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BufferedWriter` wraps a target `Writer`. When you `close()` it, it attempts to `flush` the underlying target `Writer` before closing it.

In your code, you invoke `close()` on the target `FileWriter` before invoking `close` on the `BufferedWriter`. When the `BufferedWriter#close()` tries to invoke `flush` on the `FileWriter`, that `FileWriter` is already closed and thus throws an exception.

You'll want to close `BufferedWriter` first. Better yet, use a `try-with-resources`

```
try (FileWriter write = new FileWriter(spawns, true); BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(write);) {
```